# Panic when compiling a regular expression

Tags: regex, go

I am writing a regular expression for password validation with the following code:

```
func IsPasswordValid(value string) bool {
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*$`)
    return pattern.MatchString(value)
}
```

When I execute the application, it panics:

```
Line 45: - regexp: Compile(`^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*$`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?=`
```

This regular expression works in Javascript and Ruby but not in Go. What I am do wrong here?

Comment: AS the error message said, lookahead is unsupported.

Comment: As far as I know, Lookaheads in Perl are supported at the end of a regular expression only. Even if Javascript/ruby might support it. Try not using them, and using `()` where you want to catch something.

Comment: The patten should be defined and initialized ouside the func so that it's only compiled once. Especially usefull with regexp.MustCompile as the pattern must compile at startup or else it panics. This makes it similar to a compiler error so that it can be found and fixed quickly.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs:

> The syntax of the regular expressions accepted is the same general syntax used by Perl, Python, and other languages. More precisely, it is the syntax accepted by RE2 and described at http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax, except for \C.

The RE2 wiki clearly states:

> (?=re) before text matching re **(NOT SUPPORTED)**

See also:

- http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/
- https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax

**EDIT:** if you *really* need PCRE features, you can use a binding package, e.g. https://github.com/tuxychandru/golang-pkg-pcre/. Otherwise, try to rethink your regexp and what it should match.

Answer (score 5):

Golang's Regexp syntax is different from PCRE's (which php / javascript uses for the most part).

From https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax:

> `(?=re)`   before text matching re (NOT SUPPORTED)

//edit

Example of checking the password without RE:

```
var ErrInvalidPassword = errors.New(`The password should at least have 7 letters, at least 1 number, at least 1 upper case, at least 1 special character.`)

func VerifyPassword(pw string) error {
    if len(pw) < 10 {
        return ErrInvalidPassword
    }
    var num, lower, upper, spec bool
    for _, r := range pw {
        switch {
        case unicode.IsDigit(r):
            num = true
        case unicode.IsUpper(r):
            upper = true
        case unicode.IsLower(r):
            lower = true
        case unicode.IsSymbol(r), unicode.IsPunct(r):
            spec = true
        }
    }
    if num && lower && upper && spec {
        return nil
    }
    return ErrInvalidPassword
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/gEs6MiEPOr)

Comment: So, how can I rewrite my regular expression, that matches for golang?

Comment: maybe add an example of what kind of input you're expecting.

Comment: The password should at least 7 letters, at least 1 number, at least 1 upper case, at least 1 special character. Thanks so much.

Comment: @zero_coding Well, i'm not awake enough to figure out how to do it in Go's RE, however it's much simpler to skip the RE all together IMO, I added an example of how to do it without RE.